# In an application, do we have a way to customise the share intent object so that we add additional text in Email chooser and not in sms chooser?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In our Android application, I am using Intent to share a URL as text with apps like Email apps, SMS app. I want to add an additional text as a signature (which should be appended to the original text) only in case of choosing Email and not in case of choosing SMS. Please suggest, how I can use different text for Email and SMS? Here is the sample code I am using for simply sharing.

```
String shareBody = "Here is the share content body"; 
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here"); 
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```